# exception in getting sd card path to play audio file

Tags: android

In setting dataresource for mediaplayer getting problem,tried by passing string but showing error that it should be Uri so changed to Uri like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        System.out.println(path
                + myList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        String newpath = path
                + myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Uri data = Uri.parse("file://"+ path
                + myList.getItemAtPosition(position));
        if(mp.mediaPlayer!=null){
            mp.mediaPlayer.stop();
            mp.mediaPlayer.reset();
            mp.mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        mp.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), data);
        mp.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(newpath);
        mp.mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mp.mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

still getting this exception

```
12-21 07:53:08.284: W/System.err(32134): java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1204)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1176)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1122)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at com.srikanth.lullaby.ListFileActivity.onItemClick(ListFileActivity.java:283)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3973)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 07:53:08.294: W/System.err(32134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 07:53:08.304: W/System.err(32134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
12-21 07:53:08.304: W/System.err(32134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 07:53:08.304: W/System.err(32134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 07:53:08.304: W/System.err(32134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-21 07:53:08.304: W/System.err(32134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got:

```
mp.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), data);
```

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> `public static MediaPlayer create (Context context, Uri uri)`
>   Convenience method to create a `MediaPlayer` for a given `Uri`. On success, `prepare()` will already have been called and must not be called again.

and then you do:

```
mp.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(newpath);
```

From the documentation:

> Calling `setDataSource` ... transfers a `MediaPlayer` object in the `Idle` state to the `Initialized` state. **An `IllegalStateException` is thrown if `setDataSource()` is called in any other state.**

So the documentation is quite clear on what the problem is. The call to `setDataSource` seems completely unnecessary since you already specified the data source when you did `MediaPlayer.create`.

Comment: Got same exception with these modifications

Comment: Finally done,suppose i can able to play one song from list ,if i want to play list of songs from that list how can i play it using onCompletionListener

Comment: The state diagram on the `MediaPlayer` documentation page I linked to shows the sequence of actions you need to perform to get the player into a given state.